# PSO for solving shortest path in matlab

Tags: routing, graph, matlab, shortest-path

I crate a file that represents 16000 edges with information of start node, end node and cost in a table.

In MATLAB i want to solve shortest path with PSO algorithm. How i can solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason why you want to use particle swarm optimization in this case?

If what you really want is to find the least-cost paths, you may consider using Dijkstra's algorithm. Here is one possible implementation, written in MATLAB (there are many): https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20025-dijkstra-s-minimum-cost-path-algorithm

As you only have 16000 edges, this is likely to be fast enough.

If it is not fast enough, you'll need an optimized, compiled implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm. I am not aware of any such implementations for MATLAB, though evidently there are some for Python (see my question here: [C-based implementation of Djikstra's or Fast Marching for QGIS/Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202237/c-based-implementation-of-djikstras-or-fast-marching-for-qgis-python/202245)).